# Specifying DTD to be used by DocumentBuilders for XML parsing?

Tags: java, xml, sax, xerces, docbook

I am currently writing a tool, using Java 1.6, that brings together a number of XML files. All of the files validate to the DocBook 4.5 DTD (I have checked this using xmllint and specifying the DocBook 4.5 DTD as the --dtdvalid parameter), but not all of them include the DOCTYPE declaration.

I load each XML file into the DOM to perform the required manipulation like so:

```
private Document fileToDocument( File input ) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(false);
    factory.setIgnoringComments(false);
    factory.setValidating(false);
    factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);

    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse( input );

}
```

For the most part this has worked quite well, I can use he returned object to navigate the tree and perform the required manipulations and then write the document back out. Where I am encountering problems is with files which:

- Do not include the DOCTYPE declaration, and
- Do include entities defined in the DTD (for example &mdash; / —).

Where this is the case an exception is thrown from the builder.parse(...) call with the message:

```
[Fatal Error] :5:15: The entity "mdash" was referenced, but not declared.
```

Fair enough, it isn't declared. What I would ideally do in this instance is set the DocumentBuilderFactory to always use the DocBook 4.5 DTD regardless of whether one is specified in the file.

I did try validation using the DocBook 4.5 schema but found that this produced a number of unrelated errors with the XML. It seems like the schema might not be functionally equivalent to the DTD, at least for this version of the DocBook specification.

The other option I can think of is to read the file in, try and detect whether a doctype was set or not, and then set one if none was found prior to actually parsing the XML into the DOM.

So, my question is, is there a smarter way that I have not seen to tell the parser to use a specific DTD or ensure that parsing proceeds despite the entities not resolving (not just the &emdash; example but any entities in the XML - there are a large number of potentials)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could using an EntityResolver2 and implementing [EntityResolver2.getExternalSubset()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/EntityResolver2.html#getExternalSubset%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) help?

> ... This method can also be used with documents that have no DOCTYPE declaration. When the root element is encountered, but no DOCTYPE declaration has been seen, this method is invoked. If it returns a value for the external subset, that root element is declared to be the root element, giving the effect of splicing a DOCTYPE declaration at the end the prolog of a document that could not otherwise be valid. ...

Comment: Thanks, I did not know of the EntityResolver2 interface (only EntityResolver). Once I overloaded the suggested method, and provided the default handling for the others, I now encounter this error:  
    [Fatal Error] docbookx.dtd:101:9: Recursive entity reference "%dbnotn". (Reference path: %dbnotn -> %dbnotn -> %dbnotn)  
Based on this it appears that the DTD is now at least being applied but has other issues :).